# GeckoFX webBrowser control not loading css properly

Tags: geckofx

I have a html file along with CSS which gets properly loaded in Standalone FireFox browser and also in Web Preview control(Chromium ) for Chrome. Same script does not show up rightly in on GeckoWebBrowser. CSS is not taking effect.

Buttons which are to be stacked vertically are all displayed horizontally aligned.

Currently Ia m using Chromium for Chrome and GeckoFX for Firefox.
Please suggest any other latest web browser control which can be used for Firefox.

Please suggest what could be wrong.

Comment: Post some code that shows the error and what you've tried so far: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Maybe your content type is off, see https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-29.0/issues/60/css-applied-incorrectly-using
Also, there are certainly other .NET Browser controls you could look into, e.g. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp

Comment: Here is the code

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    
    .grid-container{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 100vw;
        grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto auto; 
        grid-template-areas: 
        "header"
        "mainarea"
        "footer" 
        "navbar"
        "sidebar";
    }

Comment: here is the HTML where the above css is applied

Comment: <body>
        <div class="grid-container">
                    
            <div class="header">              <h1>DUMMY TITLE BAR</h1>            </div>  
                   
            <div class="navbar">    
              <button id="btn-Aufgabe-1">nav 1</button>
              <button id="btn-Aufgabe-2">nav 2</button>
              <button id="btn-Aufgabe-3">nav 3</button>
             
              <button id="btn-Aufgabe-10">nav 10</button> 
            
            </div>

            <div class="mainarea">   </div>          
          
        </div>
    </body>

Comment: IN actual Firefox the HTML gets loaded perfectly fine but in GeckFX webBrowser below areas get stacked one on top of other."header"
        "mainarea"
        "footer" 
        "navbar"
        "sidebar";